# Excel pivot table calculated field not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Here is an example of the sort of data I'm working with:

[image]

I would like to create a pivot table where the rows are the dates, the columns are the regions, and the values are the percent of total daily transactions that came from that region. So my desired output looks like:

[image]

I created a Calculated Field called "PercentOfDailyTransactions" with the formula COUNT(Amount)/'Total Daily Transactions'. Then I created a pivot table with value equal to Sum of PercentOfDailyTransactions.

[image]

However, this appears to be calculating 1/(total daily transactions x number of transactions in that region on that day), rather than (number of transactions in that region on that day)/(total daily transactions). For instance, 1/2/2021 in West region should be 3/6=0.5 but is instead 0.0555=1/(3*6). How is Excel getting this value, and how do I create a calculated field that calculates my desired output?

Note that if I add a column to my source table with the formula COUNT([@Amount])/[@[Total Daily Transactions]], then create a pivot table whose values are the sum of that field, that gives me the correct result. However, I would like to be able to accomplish this without adding such a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional step: I would format your base data set as a table. It might help you later if you're creating more Pivot charts, reporting connections, adding slicers, etc.

[Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pysMQ.png)

Steps:

1. Select your data and create a defualt Pivot table
2. In the *PivotTable Fields*, drag region into *columns*, date into *rows*, and total daily transactions into *values*. The default for total daily transactions in the *Values* field is set to *Sum*, so left click that -> *Value field settings* -> *Count*
3. Right click on any data point in the Pivot table -> *Show value as* -> *% of row total*
4. Done

You can repeat the same steps for *Amount*, excpet that in the *Value field settigns*, you keep that as *Sum*.

Comment: Thank you! My real data set is formatted as a table, I just made a test to point out the issue I was having.

Comment: Sorry one other question - what if I want to show the values as a % of something else that is constant across the rows? Say instead of Total Daily Transactions, there was a field Total Daily Goal that was, say, equal to 5 for all the 1/1/2021 rows and 8 for all the 1/2/2021 rows? So the desired output would be 1/5, 2/5, 1/5, 0 in the first row and 1/8, 1/8, /8, 3/8 in the second. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you mean that in addition to the total daily transactions (TDT) column, there'd be another one for total daily goal (TDG)? There's certainly a way to do that, but I'm not sure whether the way you have your data structured makes it easy. I don't see a reason why you'd want to add a goal for each row when the rows categorically differ only by east/north/west/south. What I mean is that if your goal for all regions on a particular day is X number of transactions, and you have 1k transactions on that day, it's messy to be putting that same X inside every row for that day....

Comment: The "why" is not so important because this is a toy data set made up to demonstrate what I'd like to do. In my actual data set, the number I'd like to divide by corresponds to the count of distinct regions across a given day, so 3 for 1/1/2021 and 4 for 1/2/2021. (I know this doesn't make sense for the toy data set, but again it's just for demonstrating structurally what I'd like to accomplish).

Comment: ....I think it'd be better if that goal was set somewhere else rather than in the columns next to each transaction, and the goal would could be set for any day and (and a combination of) region(s). One things that's clear is that you cant put TDG in the Values field because Excel doesn't give you the option not to summarize the values in some way, like avg, count, sum, etc. So it can go either in columns or rows. There, similarly to the previous task, you can right click on any value -> show value as -> % of -> choose Goal...

Comment: ...I tried to play with the above steps but for some reason, it's not working. Regardless of if I choose the base item to be previous/next/5/8, Excel seems to be calculating something else. Sorry I could'nt directly help with this one. Alternatively, you could try to simply to add a new column next to the pivot table and simply use a standard excel formula to do the calculation there.

Comment: Average or max would both give the correct value for total daily goal. I'm happy to have the total daily goals summarized by date in a separate table, but then I don't see how to use them in the pivot table. Right now I am doing as you suggested and calculating it in a separate table, but I was hoping I could do this directly with pivot tables to make it easier to update when my source data changes. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Ah okay, now it makes sense when you say that in the original data set, you're using distinct regions across a given day. You rightly pointed out that average or would work--which I didn't think about--but that's only when the goal for any particular day is the same across all regions. The question is also what you're planning to do with the Pivot table. If you create a separate column for goals next to the pivot table and correctly reference/match/filter/vlookup the corresponding data in the Pivot table, you should be fine even if the source data changes, but making charts won't be easy.

Comment: There's a video on youtube from MyOnlineTrainingHub called "Trick Excel into Creating Regular Charts from PivotTables - 3 Easy Techniques". I understand that you might not necessarily want to create charts, but since the prerequisite to create regular chrats from Pivot tables is to first create regular tables from pivot tables, this might help you with the necessary functions and ways to use them. Once you've managed to make a regular table that correctly references the Pivot one, adding things like another column for daily goals should be easy.